# What does 0u mean in c#?

Tags: c#

What does `0u` mean in c#? Sample context:

```
uint n = _seconds;
while (n > 0u) {
    // TODO
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var a = 0U; // a is unsigned int
```

Same as

```
var a = (uint)0; // a is unsigned int
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

It means the same thing as `((uint)0)`.

Comment: I'm interested by this actually: is there any downside (theoretically) to explicitly casting a literal as in your example, compared to declaring it using a type suffix? I kinda assume the compiler compiles the same result anyway, but....

Answer (score 6):

Much like 0L defines 0 as a long, 0u defines 0 as an unsigned int (`uint`).

Comment: Use 0L instead. It is harder to confuse with 01.

Answer (score 3):

it is a short suffix for a `uint` (or unsigned integer)

Nice summary here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix